# Meaning of double colon $::$

Tags: notation

I've came across this expression regarding function composition in some notes by people from computer science, and I don't know what the notation "$::$" means.

\begin{equation}
g \circ f : A \rightarrow C :: a \mapsto g(f(a))
\end{equation}

I get what this expression is trying to tell me, but I am pretty disturbed by the fact that I don't know what "$::$" means exactly and how to read it. Can anyone tell me what is "$::$"?

Comment: Any way you could post the notes? CS uses a *lot* of overloaded notation, so there's no way we can tell you what it means without some context.

Comment: It is just an example of a category, specifically the category of sets and functions. I've found this specific example in a PhD thesis, but similar notation is used the following notes as well:https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/teaching/materials16-17/catsproofsprocs/handout-01.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It stands for "given by" or "defined by". The function $g \circ f$ is a function from $A$ to $C$ which maps $a$ to $g(f(a))$.

Comment: Is this a common notation in computer science? This is the first time I encountered this notation.

Comment: @Jerry I've seen it before, though it's not common in algorithms or complexity.